# Point to a specific commit in a git repository in the DESCRIPTION file of an R package

Tags: r, git, devtools, r-package

When I create a `DESCRIPTION` file using devtools I know I can put git repository in the Remotes section.

The [official vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/vignettes/dependencies.html) explains how to specify a specific commit when using a github repository by adding a line like `hadley/testthat@c67018fa4970`.

I would like to use however a `git` type of remote adding a line like:

`git::https://mycompany/project.git`

How can I specify the commit in this case?

Comment: A git (source) repository is a good release tool. Release a version, place it into a (package) repository.  Setting those up, and using them, is trivial using [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html).  And you can point to those via `Additional_repositories` field.

Comment: thanks @DirkEddelbuettel! I can't really understand though: my code is already in a git repository how using drat would make me get the version at  a specific commit?

Comment: It is a _deeper_ point about git repositories being fundamentally unsuited for code releases.  As for [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) it holds _releases_: clearly marked tarballs with clearly identifable versions feeding into a decades-old, refined and working system of _dependencies_ and _package management_.  But you don't have to use that. Your call.